# Led light not blinking and staying in other function for one second

Tags: c, microcontroller

I am trying to figure out why my led light is not blinking. I have another function called Wakeablewait that should count about 1 second with the led either on or off. If the button is clicked before the timer erupts it return false (although at a further point it will switch to another function). The caution led controls the color outputs. Not sure what I am missing. In the log statements it shows that I am entering both functions over and over but the led light just stays yellow (I use two leds to make the yellow color by the way). Anyone have a clue what I am missing?

Button pressed equates to 0 on the microcontroller, and 1 when not.

```
//This time spec is in nano seconds but equates to 10ms
const struct timespec sleepTime = { 0, 10000000 };

GPIO_Value_Type previous_button_value = BUTTON_UNPRESSED;

bool WakeableWait(int btnA, int milliseconds) {
    Log_Debug("In Wake\n");

    while (milliseconds > 0) {
        // Return true if full time elapsed, false if button was pressed
        GPIO_Value_Type value;
        GPIO_GetValue(btnA, &value);

        bool button_got_pressed = (previous_button_value == BUTTON_UNPRESSED) && (value == BUTTON_PRESSED);
        previous_button_value = value;

        if (button_got_pressed) {
            return false;
        }

        nanosleep(&sleepTime, NULL);
        milliseconds -= 10;

        return true;
    }

}
// This function should blink Yellow until button A is pressed to switch to typical working traffic light
void caution_light(int y1, int y2, int btnA) {
    //// This should blink on and off for one second
    while (true) {
        // Turn on Yellow
        GPIO_SetValue(y1, GPIO_Value_Low);
        GPIO_SetValue(y2, GPIO_Value_Low);

        // Switch to other function to wait time
        Log_Debug("Turning On\n");
        WakeableWait(btnA,1000);
 
        //Turn Led off
        GPIO_SetValue(y1, GPIO_Value_High);
        GPIO_SetValue(y2, GPIO_Value_High);

        // Leave to other function 
        Log_Debug("Turning Off\n");
        WakeableWait(btnA, 1000);
    }
}
```

Image of output in Visual Studio:

[image: Output in visual studio]

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WakeableWait` does not loop. No matter what, it only does one iteration, and returns immediately: the `return true;` statement is a part of the loop body. Your LEDs are likely blinking at 100 Hz (every 10 milliseconds), and your eyes cannot detect it (what you *should* see is that the LEDs are dimmer than normal). The solution is to pull `return true;` out of the loop.

```
WakeableWait(....)
{
    while (milliseconds > 0) {
        ....
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Wish I caught that. Thank you.